# Why my chart is not loading in partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, partials

I am an angular bie and trying to make a chart in a partial, I am using a little bit animation to display partials, my main work is to display charts I am using a template for charts which i have downloaded from this website http://blacktie.co/2014/07/dashgum-free-dashboard/ and I added all the required css and js in my project.

The thing is the code of my chart does work if I place it in my index.html file after I remove `ng-view` but if I remove the code and place my chart code in `page-tps` partial the code does not load the chart.

My index.html file look like this

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Point of sale</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="global-wrap">
            <div class="page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div> // if i remove ng-view and place my page-tps code and run my index file the chart does load

        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
        <script src="js/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--common script for all pages-->
        <script src="js/common-scripts.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my partial file `page-tps`

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 ">
                      <!--CUSTOM CHART START -->
                      <div class="border-head">
                          <h3>VISITS</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="custom-bar-chart">
                          <ul class="y-axis">
                              <li><span>10.000</span></li>
                              <li><span>8.000</span></li>
                              <li><span>6.000</span></li>
                              <li><span>4.000</span></li>
                              <li><span>2.000</span></li>
                              <li><span>0</span></li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="bar">
                              <div class="title">JAN</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="8.500" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">85%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bar ">
                              <div class="title">FEB</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="5.000" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">50%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bar ">
                              <div class="title">MAR</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="6.000" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">60%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bar ">
                              <div class="title">APR</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="4.500" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">45%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bar">
                              <div class="title">MAY</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="3.200" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">32%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bar ">
                              <div class="title">JUN</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="6.200" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">62%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bar">
                              <div class="title">JUL</div>
                              <div class="value tooltips" data-original-title="7.500" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">75%</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--custom chart end-->
                    </div><!-- /row -->
```

My controller.js

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
var posControllers = angular.module('posControllers', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);
posControllers.controller('PosController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', '$modal', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, $modal) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';
        $scope.submitForm = function (username, password) {
            $scope.username = username;
            $scope.password = password;
            $scope.showUsername = false;
            $scope.showPassword = false;
            if ($scope.username === 'usman' && $scope.password === '1122')
            {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'partials/popup.html',
                });
                $location.path('/admin');
            }
            else if ($scope.username !== 'usman')
            {
                $scope.showUsername = true;
            }
            else if ($scope.password !== '1122')
            {
                $scope.showPassword = true;
            }
        };
    }]);
posControllers.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-admin';
    }]);
posControllers.controller('TpsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-tps';
    }]);
posControllers.controller('TsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-ts';
    }]);
posControllers.controller('PaController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-pa';
    }]);
posControllers.controller('PcController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-pc';
    }]);
posControllers.controller('CpController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-cp';
    }]);
posControllers.controller('CrController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-cr';
    }]);
```

Plus just to mention here, I am using some animation which I followed through this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview which I believe has nothing to do with my problem.

**Plunker**

Here is the link of plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ASaasx3laUHYDPfLnsn9?p=preview   username is `usman` and password is `1122` when you click on top product sales you can see the graph. But when you copy and paste the same code of TOP product sales in index.html at the place of `<div class="page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div>` the chart will come

Comment: post your controller code or create a plunker

Comment: i think the problem is your chart expect the dom to be there on page load and in your case js for chart is executed before the partial loaded. that is why it is working when you put your partial code in your index.html

Comment: so what should I do now @atul

Comment: Actually it is difficult to tell just by reading the code. It will be more helpful if you can provide the fiddle where the code can be run and debug. or else try to some how deffer the execution of js for chart (e.g timeout).

Comment: I have created the plunker you can see it

Comment: Rather than using the above method I followed this link very much impressive https://css-tricks.com/using-angularjs-for-data-visualisations/